# Spectral triple on $\mathcal C(M)$ where $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold, not necessarily spin

Tags: continuity, riemannian-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, compact-manifolds, noncommutative-geometry

I have been reading Alain Connes' [*Compact metric spaces, Fredholm modules and hyperfiniteness*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/ergodic-theory-and-dynamical-systems/article/compact-metric-spaces-fredholm-modules-and-hyperfiniteness/2ACB2EBA0AA0A40F9D890AA9915500F7).

In proposition 1, it is mentioned that an unbounded Fredholm module (nowadays: spectral triple) over $C(M)$, where $M$ is a compact, spin [Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold) is as follows: the representing Hilbert space $L^2(M, S)$ is the space of spinors acting on $M$ and the self-adjoint operator $D$ is the Dirac operator.

If we drop the spin assumption, what would be a "standard" unbounded Fredholm module over $C(M)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One standard example is formed by considering the space $L^2(M;\Lambda^\ast T^\ast M)$ of differential forms with operator $D=d+d^\ast$, where $d$ is the exterior derivative and $d^\ast$ is its formal $L^2$-adjoint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If you permit, two follow-up questions: Can this spectral triple be even? And is the triple you gave sometimes referred to as the Hodge-de-Rham triple?

Comment: Yes to both questions.  Evenness comes from the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading given by the parity of the degree of a differential form (i.e. multiplication by $(-1)^{deg}$).

Comment: One [these slides](https://www.noncommutativegeometry.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/GNCG-Magee.pdf), p. 11 they instead take the Dirac operator $- i (d - d^*)$. This is qualitatively different, right?